# Backbone View not initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am an absolute beginner to backbone js and have been trying to follow along the lines of [this GIT repo](https://github.com/ngauthier/intro-to-backbone-js). Below is the bare minimum code I have put in.

```
(function() {

var MWLivePreview = {};
window.MWLivePreview = MWLivePreview;

var MWTemplate = function(name) {
    return _.template($("#" + name + "-template").html());
}

var log = function(logit) {
    console.log(logit);
}

MWLivePreview.Index = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: MWTemplate('live-preview'),
    render: function() {
        log(this.template(this));
        this.$el.html(this.template(this));
        return this;
    }
});

MWLivePreview.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {

        this.el = options.el
    },

    routes: {
        "": "index"
    },

    index: function() {
        var view = new MWLivePreview.Index();

        this.el.empty();
        this.el.append(view.render().el);
    }
});

MWLivePreview.boot = function(container) {
    container = $(container);
    var router = new MWLivePreview.Router({el: container});
    Backbone.history.start();
}

})()
```

Code below is the template that I have:

```
<script type="text/template" id="live-preview-template">
    <div> We have got few templates</div>
</script>
```

And I am wiring up the whole thing by calling the code below on document ready

```
MWLivePreview.boot($("#asapatterns"));
```

I am not really sure where I went wrong but this returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a){return new m(a)} has no method 'pick'
```

Any ideas or clues on what might be going wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

Removing `Backbone.history.start()` stops giving the error but again nothing comes up in the view.

Comment: Do you know the line number where the error occurred? Are you loading underscore js on your page?

Comment: @Matt: The last endpoint in the stack trace is on line 
`var view = new MWLivePreview.Index();`
Underscore js is on the page and loaded in the order it should be

Comment: Random guess: your underscore.js version does not match the one required by Backbone (underscore 1.4.3 for Backbone 0.9.10)

Comment: @nikoshr: Holy! fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://backbonejs.org/

> Backbone's only hard dependency is either [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/).

but be careful to match the version required by Backbone: at the time of writing, underscore.js 1.4.3 for Backbone 0.9.10